# Is there a way to cancel or disable the slow dock transition easter eggs?

Tags: dock

If you shift-click the minimize button or hold shift while restoring a window, you get the slow-motion genie or scale effect.

Is there a way to resume full speed after an accidental shift-click?
Is there a way to disable the shift-click combination so that the transition always runs at full speed?

Comment: Same with exposé

Comment: I have never seen the point in this, fun to do once, but whats the point, anyone have a use?

Answer (score 4):

There is a way!

Open Terminal.app

Then, type this and type the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder FXEnableSlowAnimation -bool false
```

To make it go on again, just change the `false` to `true`.

**Edit:**

It seems that there is no way to disable the Slow Animation special effects on shift-click.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Snow Leopard.

Comment: Are you sure? I am almost positive that I did this on my computer - I will check when I get home...

Comment: Yep, [here's a question from SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/121472/how-to-disable-slow-motion-effect-in-mac-os-x-shift-key/121474#121474) where other users report this not working in Snow Leopard.